# Python Crontab permanent registered

Tags: python-2.7, cron

I have setup Python CronTab in SSH Cloud Linux like this:

```
ipython

from crontab import CronTab; cron = CronTab('user');
for job in cron: print job

job  = cron.new(command='ipython  /home/batch_query.py   &>> /home/logfile_batch.txt', comment='b01')
job.day.on(21);  job.enable()

cron.write( 'bb.tab' )

for job in cron: print job
```

However, when leaving the SSH session, the cron is not anymore registered.
how to make permanently registered in the linux ?

Answer (score 0):

If you write the cron out to a tab file, then you've not written it out to the user account. If you want the user to have a modified tab, you should write it back to the user's crontab.

```
cron = CronTab(user='user')
cron.do_some_stuff(...)
cron.write()
```